# Extremely Slow Image Pulls Docker Private Registry

Tags: ssh, docker, ansible, gitlab, ci

I have two servers:

1.Server-1 (GitLab-CE & Private docker registry)

2.Server-2 (Staging)

After build stage and push container to registry inside GitLab CI, next stage is deploy(CD) using Ansible. When Ansible connect to remote server(Server-2), run task docker-compose pull,docker very very slow pull image(~1.2GB) that built an pushed to my registry(Server-1).

In another scenario I manually pull this image in another server and same server (Server-2), it pull fast whithout any issue.

How to solve this issue inside Ansible or Gitlab?

Additional Information:

- Docker version: 20.6
- Gitlab version: 14.0
- I using docker DinD GitLab runner service
- I using cbhek/ansible-worker:1.0.0 for Ansible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was network problem on server.